# What does the Rockstar Games Social Club Division mean?

Tags: rockstar-games-social-club

When you're in Social Club what does "the division" mean? Like is that your rank in the club? Example: 6-20 division.

Answer (score 2):

It means how many members basically. If you have 1-5 crew members you are placed in that division to compete with other 1-5 crews on the leaderboards etc.

[Source](http://gtaforums.com/topic/616901-question-about-social-club/)